# expect script global error logging

Tags: logging, automation, expect

I want to implement error handling for my expect script.
My main problem is that the expect commands only wait and not abort if they do not match. I figured out how to react on a timeout.

```
expect {
  timeout exit
  "Name."
}
```

I would have to specify an action for timeouts for every expect command.
Is there a way to define a global behavior for every expect command?

I would like to log the received output and the previous send command

Answer (score 1):

You can use `expect_after` or `expect_before`:

> **expect_after [expect_args]**
>
> > works identically to the *expect_before* except  that  if  patterns
> >      from  both  *expect* and *expect_after* can match, the *expect* pattern
> >      is used.
>
> **expect_before [expect_args]**
>
> > takes the same arguments as *expect*, however  it  returns
> >     immediately.   Pattern-action  pairs from the most recent *expect_before*
> >     with the same spawn id are  implicitly  added  to  any  following
> >     *expect*  commands.   If  a pattern matches, it is treated as if it
> >     had been specified in the *expect* command itself, and the  associated
> >     body  is executed in the context of the *expect* command.  If
> >     patterns from  both  *expect_before*  and  *expect*  can  match,  the
> >     *expect_before* pattern is used.
> >     ... ...

Following is a simple example:

```
[STEP 101] $ cat foo.exp
spawn bash --noprofile --norc
expect_after timeout {
    incr n_timeout
    send "echo 'timeout #$n_timeout'\r"
}

set timeout 2
set n_timeout 0
expect {
    foo {}
}
expect {
    bar {}
}

send "exit\r"
expect eof
[STEP 102] $ expect foo.exp
spawn bash --noprofile --norc
bash-4.3$ echo 'timeout #1'
timeout #1
bash-4.3$ echo 'timeout #2'
timeout #2
bash-4.3$ exit
exit
[STEP 103] $
```